# Asp.Net FileUpload doesn't work on Ajax UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-ajax, file-upload

I have an ASP.Net FileUpload inside an UpdatePanel. When I click on a save button inside the same updatepanel and check on serverside if that control hasFile it is allways false.

Where is my error? Do I need to post the entire page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately due to javascript sandboxing you will need to post the entire page